# How to check file name contain any date in it name in Java?

Tags: java

I need to check a filename contain any date or number in its name and if it contain to change the name accordingly.

Example 1

```
phd_20001_pat_apr.txt.gz
```

In above example filename contain 20001. So i want to change it accordingly-

```
phd_*_pat_apr*
```

example2

```
phd_pat_mnc.txt.gz
```

In above example no date or number present in filename. So it won't be change.

Could you please tell me what are the changes I do in the below code to get the desirable output-

`filename`  & `source_file_nm` are header.

```
if ( (((java.util.List<String>)globalMap.get("filename")).get(i)).contains("enc_prov") )
                                      {
    globalMap.put("source_file_nm",(((java.util.List<String>)globalMap.get("filename")).get(i)).substring(0,(((java.util.List<String>)globalMap.get("filename")).get(i)).lastIndexOf("_")+2));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code? instead of just an if block

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65249897/how-to-match-a-date-which-is-inside-a-file-name) of your previous question. Try to improve that question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for that

```
String filenamePattern = "phd_[0-9]+_.*"
 try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(folder,
                                              Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                              (path,
                                               basicFileAttributes) -> path.toFile().getName().matches(filenamePattern))) {
            return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

This will return a List of all files matching filenamePattern. Change the [maxDepth the maximum number of directory levels to search] on files.find accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can take below approach to achieve your target

1. Using a regex check if file name contains any number
2. If yes, than split the string into characters and replace it with *